# Convert Object Column to integer or float

Tags: python, object, type-conversion, integer

I have a data set that looks like that...(shortened for the question here).

```py
DataFrame Name = ObjectIntTest
```

[Most of the columns/labels are varios objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YapQc.png)

Label ISIN = Various ISINs like IE00B3XXRP09, IE00BF553838,LU0950668870

To run a logistic regression I need to convert for example this various ISINs to integers
(the integer/float then always needs to be the same for the ISIN IE00B3XXRP09 and IE00BF553838)

I tried various ways like these ones but I only get errors:

```py
ObjectIntTest['ISIN'] = ObjectIntTest.ISIN.astype(int) = ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'IE00B3XXRP09'

ObjectIntTest['ISIN'] = ObjectIntTest['ISIN'].astype(float) = ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'IE00B3XXRP09'

ObjectIntTest['ISIN'] = ObjectIntTest['ISIN'].astype(str).astype(int) = ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'IE00B3XXRP09'

ObjectIntTest = pd.to_numeric(ObjectIntTest['ISIN']) = ValueError: Unable to parse string "IE00B3XXRP09" at position 0
```

Sorry I'm new to python and programming but need to find as solution to make this data usable for logistic regression...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Joe,

Your ISIN code contains letters and numbers. That is what is causing the value error.

Comment: Thx Lukas, but i cant change that since that is the International Securities Identification Number.

Comment: You need to use an appropriate hashing function since ISIN values can't be cast to int/float.

Comment: @joe5555 Can you replace the image link with a transcribed text since the image is blurry and also may not last for a long time.

Comment: @AshokArora: done and thanks for your help. Isnt there a better solution, cause there are about 500 different ISINs in the original file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISIN seems to be a categorical feature, hence representing it with integer (which you can compare and do arithmetics on) can cause problems.

Usually categorical values are encoded using one of the encoding techniques, the most popular are One Hot Encoding and Label Encoding. Label Encoding maps each unique categorical value to an integer (which is not really good considering what I said), while One Hot replaces your categorical column with N columns, each containing one of values [0, 1] and representing one of possible unique categorical value. You might wanna read more about, for example [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/03/one-hot-encoding-vs-label-encoding-using-scikit-learn/).

In case you don't have enormous amount unique values in your ISIN column, One Hot suits better. You can use [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on your categorical column to apply One Hot encoding.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Use a key-value mapping using Python's dictionary to map an `int` to a `string`.
2. Use a separate hashing function such as Python's built-in `hash`. eg.

```py
>>> hash('IE00B3XXRP09')
2571740993647531361

>>> type(hash('IE00B3XXRP09'))
<class 'int'>
```